# Insert Bootstrap WYSIWYG

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to insert this script (https://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/) to my site, but I don't know how to do that exactely. Can anyone explain how to insert this into my HTML-code? Or is there a better bootstrap plugin for text editing?

Right now my code looks like this:

```
<form action="" method="POST">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="artikel-titel">Titel</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="artikel-titel" name="titel" placeholder="Titel">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" id="editor">
        <label for="artikel-content">Innehåll</label>
        <textarea rows="10" class="form-control" id="artikel-content" name="content"></textarea>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Spara" class="btn btn-primary">

</form>
```

Edit:
I found this script and that fits my project better, so now I wounder how I insert it on my site (the code is above) and how to activate the translations?

http://bootstrap-wysiwyg.github.io/bootstrap3-wysiwyg/

Answer (score 0):

Download or copy paste code of file from [here](https://github.com/mindmup/bootstrap-wysiwyg/blob/master/bootstrap-wysiwyg.js), put this file in your project directory.

```
<script src="bootstrap-wysiwyg.js"></script>
```

To include bootsrap wysiwyg plugin in current scope - only if you're in the same directory as bootstrap-wysiwyg.js file script, if you not, you must give path to bootstrap-wysiwyg.js file from current scope localisation.

Next place some div with specific id attribute - that will be your wysiwyg container:

```
<div id="your_id_name" style="overflow:scroll; max-height:300px"></div>
```

(You can declare style in main style file or wherever you want write: `#your_id_name` is the reference) or leave it in attribute like above.

Last thing is initiate plugin, write this after `div` or place initiation code between script tags in your main javascript file:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> $('#your_id_name').wysiwyg(); </script>
```

Also make sure you have jQuery on board, if not:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you please integrate it into my code because I don't get it to work... The thing is that I use a text area to type in.